# Get just the name from mysql_query resource

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db-select

```
$agent_query=mysql_query("
                            SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$agent_id'
                        ");
$get_agent_name=mysql_fetch_assoc($agent_query);            
$this->session->agent=$get_agent_name['name'];
```

I know the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, but is there a way I can get just the name without running any loop in Zend?

Comment: What doesn't work with your current code? It looks valid to me.

Comment: What does Zend have to do with this? Even Assuming you mean the Zend Framework - there are no Zend Framework database components in use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php function [mysql_result](http://php.net/mysql_result) can be used to return a single field for a query by specifying the row and column you want returned. As there is only 1 row and column for your query (I assume), they will always be 0 and 0.

```
$name = mysql_result($agent_query, 0, 0);
```